# How can I add users to a role in MarkLogic over REST?

Tags: marklogic

Using the MarkLogic out of the box rest APIs, how can I add a user to a role?

I see that I could use [sec:user-add-roles](https://docs.marklogic.com/sec:user-add-roles), if I were executing server side javascript/xquery.

I also see the [Manage API users put request](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/manage/v2/roles/[id-or-name]/properties) would let me update a user, but updating a user means I could change username, password, and add any role. This also requires higher privileges than I want a user to have.

How can I get the functionality of the sec:user-add-roles function over the rest API?

Answer (score 0):

You can lock down the Manage API a bit via granular privileges - https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/granular

But if that's still too open for your requirements, I think you'd need to make a custom endpoint that allows for updating users and also enforces your particular security requirements.

Answer (score -1):

If you're gonna' go down the custom endpoint route, consider [XQRS](https://consulting.xmllondon.com/xqrs).

```
declare
  %rest:GET
  %rest:path("/security/user/{$user}/add-roles")
  %rest:query-param("role", "${role}")
  %xdmp:update
function add-roles($user as xs:string, $role as xs:string*) {
  sec:user-add-roles($user, $role)
};
```

That would allow you to send a GET request along the lines of:

```
/security/user/jim/add-roles?role=merge&role=alert-user
```